# How to display a single image with html in Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, image, mime-types, file-get-contents

I want to display an image from my database, stored as a blob. The Blade file to view the picture is as follows.

```php
<div class="col-lg-7"> 
    <img src="{{ url('images/' . $id )}} "/>
</div>
```

I tried to replace with this code:

```
  <img style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;" src="{{ url('images/' . $id) }} " />
```

It shows the view in the page like this:

[image: view image]

I use the following function in my web route to get the image.

```php
// Get profile image
Route::get('images/{id}', function ($id) {
    // Find the user
    $item = App\Itemregistration::find($id);

    // Return the image in the response with the correct MIME type
    return response()->make($item->Picture, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME))->buffer($item->Picture)
    ));
});
```

Previously I was able to display the picture; the image is stored in the images folder. However, after a few developments in another area, suddenly I just noticed the picture could not be displayed. I had checked using URL (for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/210) the image is downloaded as an unknown file. I had compared the code with the previous version; it is the same. I am confused, what caused the problem.

Do anyone has an idea which way to identify the problem? Am I missing something or change something accidentally?Thanks.

Comment: what is wong with it?

Comment: <div>{{ id }}</div> produce http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profil/210

Comment: i have used the same code before and it displays correctly. only after some development, I don't know what caused its failure

Comment: in the page it shows broken page icon with link http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/3 embedded in it..if I copy the link and open in browser the file downloded as unknown file not viewed in the browser

Comment: of course, it is local..No image displayed, it appears as downloaded file unknown format.

Comment: it does not work..I update the question with the output

Comment: I think the problem is when the image cannot be stored in the image folder, means the function in the route not working properly..but I don't know why..

Comment: thank you for your suggestion..I had just configured that the problem is caused by image column format changed during development..that's why the code cannot read and retrieve the image.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to just render the image in the view directly, rather than define a function and then use it as you've done?

```
    <img src="{{asset('your_image_folder_path'.$image->name)}}">
```

I see you are trying to access the image by it so maybe you can also do something like such:

```
    public function methodName($id)
    {
       $image= YourImageModel::find($id);
       return view('your_view_with_compacted_image_variable');

    }
```

Comment: I am accessing blob file from db(picture) to be displayed in the blade..so the function turn blob file to an image to be displayed..

Comment: thank you for your suggestion..I had just configured that the problem is caused by image column format changed during development..that's why the code cannot read and retrieve the image..